# How could I create my own custom .zip format in python34?

Tags: python-3.x, zip

I want to make my own zip file [similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29210572/how-would-i-create-my-own-zip-like-file) but in python 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in creating your own ZIP file, you might be interested in checking out the following two files. The first provides a GUI interface for compressing and decompressing directories, and the second has classes that use a custom serialization format. Use this idea to create your own system.

---

**Archive3.py**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
"""Provide an efficient alternative to zipping directories into archives.

This simple application is designed to serialize and deserialize directories
and their files into BZ2 compressed files. No active progress is shown, but
the window reappears once the requested operations have been completed."""


# Import the compression library along with tools to create a GUI on screen.
import bz2
import pathlib
import tkinter.filedialog
import tkinter.messagebox
import tkinter.ttk


# Import the custom serialization module to handle directories.
import daf_stream


# Include supplemental information along with a public API definition.
__author__ = 'Stephen "Zero" Chappell <Noctis.Skytower@gmail.com>'
__date__ = '21 February 2017'
__version__ = 3, 0, 0
__all__ = 'Application', 'find_parent_of_type'


class Application(tkinter.ttk.Frame):

    """Application(master=None, **kw) -> Application instance"""

    # Define some of the options used when dealing with directories and files.
    DIRECTORY_OPTIONS = dict(
        initialdir=pathlib.Path.home(),
        mustexist=True
    )
    FILE_OPTIONS = dict(
        defaultextension='.caa',
        filetypes=['Archive .caa'],
        initialdir=pathlib.Path.home()
    )

    @classmethod
    def main(cls):
        """Create a root window and display an Application instance in it."""
        tkinter.NoDefaultRoot()
        root = tkinter.Tk()
        root.title('Archive 3')
        root.resizable(False, False)
        frame = cls(root)
        frame.grid(sticky=tkinter.NSEW)
        root.mainloop()

    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):
        """Initialize the Application's instance attributes."""
        super().__init__(master, **kw)
        self.label = self.compress_button = self.decompress_button = None
        self.create_widgets()
        self.configure_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        """Build the controls the application will shown on screen."""
        self.label = tkinter.ttk.Label(
            self,
            text='''\
WARNING:
This program is not backward-compatible and
cannot be used with the Archive 2.0 program.''',
            justify=tkinter.CENTER
        )
        self.compress_button = tkinter.ttk.Button(
            self,
            text='Compress Directory to File',
            command=lambda: self.wrapper(self.compress_directory)
        )
        self.decompress_button = tkinter.ttk.Button(
            self,
            text='Decompress File to Directory',
            command=lambda: self.wrapper(self.decompress_file)
        )

    def configure_widgets(self):
        """Set up the controls so they show up in their frame."""
        options = dict(padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tkinter.NSEW)
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0, **options)
        self.compress_button.grid(row=1, column=0, **options)
        self.decompress_button.grid(row=2, column=0, **options)

    def wrapper(self, method):
        """Handle the root window, execute the method, and show any errors."""
        root = find_parent_of_type(self, tkinter.Tk)
        root.withdraw()
        try:
            method()
        except Exception as error:
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror(
                'Exception',
                f'{type(error).__name__}: {error}',
                master=self
            )
        root.deiconify()

    def compress_directory(self):
        """Pick a source and serialize it to the destination."""
        source = tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory(
            parent=self,
            title='Where is the directory you want to archive?',
            **self.DIRECTORY_OPTIONS
        )
        if source:
            destination = tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(
                confirmoverwrite=True,
                parent=self,
                title='Where should the compressed file be saved?',
                **self.FILE_OPTIONS
            )
            if destination:
                with bz2.open(destination, 'wb') as destination:
                    daf_stream.Serializer(destination).run(source)

    def decompress_file(self):
        """Pick a source and deserialize it to the destination."""
        source = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(
            multiple=False,
            parent=self,
            title='Where is the file you want to decompress?',
            **self.FILE_OPTIONS
        )
        if source:
            destination = tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory(
                parent=self,
                title='Where should the data archive be loaded?',
                **self.DIRECTORY_OPTIONS
            )
            if destination:
                with bz2.open(source, 'rb') as source:
                    daf_stream.Deserializer(source).run(destination)


def find_parent_of_type(widget, desired_type):
    """Retrieve the control's parent that is of the desired type."""
    while True:
        widget = widget.master
        if widget is None:
            raise AttributeError('cannot find parent of desired type')
        if isinstance(widget, desired_type):
            return widget


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application.main()
```

---

**daf_stream.py**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
"""Provide a simple directory and file serialization protocol.

This module implements two classes that can handle the DFS (Directory &
File Serialization) file format. Both classes can deal with file-like
objects and stream directories and files to and from the file system."""


# Import other modules needed for this module to work properly.
import abc
import collections
import enum
import io
import pathlib


# Include supplemental information along with a public API definition.
__author__ = 'Stephen "Zero" Chappell <Noctis.Skytower@gmail.com>'
__date__ = '9 February 2017'
__version__ = 3, 0, 0
__all__ = 'Serializer', 'Deserializer'


# The organization of the serialized data is fairly simple as shown below.
SERIALIZATION_FORMAT = '''\
Directory
    Header
        0,aaa,b,c,dd (Bit Mapping)
            0 = Directory
            a = Pointer Length
            b = Name Size Length
            c = Content Flag
            d = Type Code
                00 = Separator
                01 = Reserved
                10 = Reserved
                11 = Genuine
    Pointer to Parent
    Name Size
    Name
---------------------------------
File
    Header
        1,aaa,b,ccc (Bit Mapping)
            1 = File
            a = Pointer Length
            b = Name Size Length
            c = Data Size Length
    Pointer to Parent
    Name Size
    Name
    Data Size
    Data
'''


@enum.unique
class _RecordType(enum.IntEnum):

    """Enumeration of the different types a record may represent."""

    DIRECTORY = 0b0
    FILE = 0b1


@enum.unique
class _DirectoryTypeCode(enum.IntEnum):

    """Enumeration of codes directories may specify for their type."""

    SEPARATOR = 0b00
    RESERVED_A = 0b01
    RESERVED_B = 0b10
    GENUINE = 0b11


# Define the necessary components used to describe a bit field.
_BitField = collections.namedtuple('_BitField', 'offset, width')


class _Common(abc.ABC):

    """Abstract class for supporting Serializer and Deserializer classes."""

    # Define a few static attributes for use in derived classes.
    BUFFER_SIZE = 1 << 20
    BYTE_WIDTH = 8
    BYTE_MASK = (1 << BYTE_WIDTH) - 1
    NAME_ENCODING = 'utf_8'     # Set to 'mbcs' for Archive 2.0 compatibility.
    NULL_BYTE = b'\0'

    # Define the bit fields used in header bytes.
    RECORD_TYPE = _BitField(7, 1)
    POINTER_LENGTH = _BitField(4, 3)
    NAME_SIZE_LENGTH = _BitField(3, 1)
    CONTENT_FLAG = _BitField(2, 1)
    DIRECTORY_TYPE_CODE = _BitField(0, 2)
    FILE_DATA_SIZE_LENGTH = _BitField(0, 3)

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, stream):
        """Initialize the _Common instance's attributes."""
        self._stream = stream
        self._header = None

    @classmethod
    def _int_to_bytes(cls, integer):
        """Convert a number into a byte string of variable length."""
        if integer:
            array = bytearray()
            while integer:
                array.insert(0, integer & cls.BYTE_MASK)
                integer >>= cls.BYTE_WIDTH
            return bytes(array)
        return cls.NULL_BYTE

    @classmethod
    def _bytes_to_int(cls, array):
        """Convert a byte string of variable length into a number."""
        integer = 0
        for byte in array:
            integer <<= cls.BYTE_WIDTH
            integer |= byte
        return integer

    @staticmethod
    def _write(file, buffer):
        """Write buffer to file until it is completely written."""
        while True:
            written = file.write(buffer)
            if written is None:
                raise IOError('nothing could be written to the file')
            if written == len(buffer):
                break
            buffer = buffer[written:]


class Serializer(_Common):

    """Serializer(destination) -> Serializer instance"""

    def __init__(self, destination):
        """Initialize the Serializer instance's attributes."""
        super().__init__(destination)
        self._started = False
        self._pointer = None

    def run(self, source, keep_zombies=True):
        """Dump the source file or directory contents onto the destination."""
        path = pathlib.Path(source).resolve()
        zombies = []
        if path.is_dir():
            self._prime_run()
            self._acquire_dir(path, self.NULL_BYTE, keep_zombies, zombies)
        elif path.is_file():
            self._prime_run()
            self._acquire_file(path, self.NULL_BYTE, keep_zombies, zombies)
        else:
            raise ValueError('source must be a dir or a file')
        return zombies

    def _prime_run(self):
        """Reset some attributes before a serialization run."""
        self._pointer = 0
        if self._started:
            self._write(self._stream, self.NULL_BYTE)
        else:
            self._started = True

    def _acquire_dir(self, source, parent, keep_zombies, zombies):
        """Serialize a directory."""
        try:
            paths = tuple(source.iterdir())
        except OSError:
            zombies.append(source)
            if not keep_zombies:
                return
            paths = ()
        self._write_complete_dir_header(source, parent, bool(paths))
        if paths:
            self._pointer += 1
            parent = self._int_to_bytes(self._pointer)
            for path in paths:
                if path.is_dir():
                    self._acquire_dir(path, parent, keep_zombies, zombies)
                elif path.is_file():
                    self._acquire_file(path, parent, keep_zombies, zombies)

    def _write_complete_dir_header(self, source, parent, content):
        """Record all directory information except its contents."""
        name = source.name.encode(self.NAME_ENCODING)
        name_size = self._int_to_bytes(len(name))
        self._write_dir_header_byte(parent, name_size, content)
        self._write(self._stream, parent)
        self._write(self._stream, name_size)
        self._write(self._stream, name)

    def _write_dir_header_byte(self, pointer, name_size, content):
        """Record the directory header byte using the correct format."""
        self._header = 0
        self._set_bits(_RecordType.DIRECTORY, self.RECORD_TYPE)
        self._set_bits(len(pointer) - 1, self.POINTER_LENGTH)
        self._set_bits(len(name_size) - 1, self.NAME_SIZE_LENGTH)
        self._set_bits(content, self.CONTENT_FLAG)
        self._set_bits(_DirectoryTypeCode.GENUINE, self.DIRECTORY_TYPE_CODE)
        self._write(self._stream, bytes([self._header]))

    def _set_bits(self, integer, bit_field):
        """Help build the header byte while checking certain arguments."""
        if not 0 <= integer < 1 << bit_field.width:
            raise ValueError('integer does not fit in width numbers of bits')
        self._header |= integer << bit_field.offset

    def _acquire_file(self, source, parent, keep_zombies, zombies):
        """Serialize a file."""
        restore_point = self._stream.tell()
        try:
            with source.open('rb') as file:
                file_length = file.seek(0, io.SEEK_END)
                self._write_complete_file_header(source, parent, file_length)
                future_data = file.seek(0, io.SEEK_END)
                if future_data != file_length:
                    raise OSError('source changed size after writing header')
                file.seek(0, io.SEEK_SET)
                while future_data:
                    buffer = file.read(min(future_data, self.BUFFER_SIZE))
                    if not buffer:
                        raise OSError('source file ended with remaining data')
                    self._write(self._stream, buffer)
                    future_data -= len(buffer)
                if file.seek(0, io.SEEK_END) != file_length:
                    raise OSError('file changed size during serialization')
        except OSError:
            self._stream.seek(restore_point, io.SEEK_SET)
            self._stream.truncate()
            zombies.append(source)
            if keep_zombies:
                self._write_complete_file_header(source, parent, 0)

    def _write_complete_file_header(self, source, parent, file_length):
        """Record all file information except its data."""
        name = source.name.encode(self.NAME_ENCODING)
        name_size = self._int_to_bytes(len(name))
        data_size = self._int_to_bytes(file_length)
        self._write_file_header_byte(parent, name_size, data_size)
        self._write(self._stream, parent)
        self._write(self._stream, name_size)
        self._write(self._stream, name)
        self._write(self._stream, data_size)

    def _write_file_header_byte(self, pointer, name_size, data_size):
        """Record the file header byte using the correct format."""
        self._header = 0
        self._set_bits(_RecordType.FILE, self.RECORD_TYPE)
        self._set_bits(len(pointer) - 1, self.POINTER_LENGTH)
        self._set_bits(len(name_size) - 1, self.NAME_SIZE_LENGTH)
        self._set_bits(len(data_size) - 1, self.FILE_DATA_SIZE_LENGTH)
        self._write(self._stream, bytes([self._header]))


class Deserializer(_Common):

    """Deserializer(source) -> Deserializer instance"""

    def __init__(self, source):
        """Initialize the Deserializer instance's attributes."""
        super().__init__(source)
        self._finished = False
        self._parents = None

    @property
    def finished(self):
        """Check if the object has reached the end of the file yet."""
        return self._finished

    def run(self, destination):
        """Load the source file-like object onto the destination directory."""
        if self._finished:
            raise EOFError('end of file was found')
        self._parents = [pathlib.Path(destination).resolve()]
        starting_run = True
        while True:
            byte = self._stream.read(1)
            if not byte:
                self._finished = True
                if starting_run:
                    raise IOError('unexpected file termination detected')
                break
            self._header = byte[0]
            if self._get_bits(self.RECORD_TYPE) == _RecordType.FILE:
                self._release_file()
            else:
                type_code = self._get_bits(self.DIRECTORY_TYPE_CODE)
                if type_code == _DirectoryTypeCode.GENUINE:
                    self._release_dir()
                elif type_code == _DirectoryTypeCode.SEPARATOR:
                    if starting_run:
                        raise IOError('empty record detected')
                    break
                else:
                    raise IOError('reserved directory type code detected')
            starting_run = False

    def _get_bits(self, bit_field):
        """Extract width number of bits from header starting at offset."""
        return self._header >> bit_field.offset & (1 << bit_field.width) - 1

    def _release_dir(self):
        """Deserialize a directory."""
        pointer_length = self._get_bits(self.POINTER_LENGTH) + 1
        name_size_length = self._get_bits(self.NAME_SIZE_LENGTH) + 1
        content_flag = bool(self._get_bits(self.CONTENT_FLAG))
        # After decoding the header byte, read and process the remaining data.
        pointer = self._bytes_to_int(self._read(pointer_length))
        name_size = self._bytes_to_int(self._read(name_size_length))
        name = self._read(name_size).decode(self.NAME_ENCODING)
        path = self._parents[pointer] / name
        path.mkdir()
        if content_flag:
            self._parents.append(path)

    def _release_file(self):
        """Deserialize a file."""
        pointer_length = self._get_bits(self.POINTER_LENGTH) + 1
        name_size_length = self._get_bits(self.NAME_SIZE_LENGTH) + 1
        data_size_length = self._get_bits(self.FILE_DATA_SIZE_LENGTH) + 1
        # After decoding the header byte, read and process the remaining data.
        pointer = self._bytes_to_int(self._read(pointer_length))
        name_size = self._bytes_to_int(self._read(name_size_length))
        name = self._read(name_size).decode(self.NAME_ENCODING)
        with (self._parents[pointer] / name).open('wb') as destination:
            future_data = self._bytes_to_int(self._read(data_size_length))
            while future_data:
                buffer = self._stream.read(min(future_data, self.BUFFER_SIZE))
                if not buffer:
                    raise IOError('end of file was found')
                self._write(destination, buffer)
                future_data -= len(buffer)

    def _read(self, future_data):
        """Read at least as many bytes from the source as requested."""
        if future_data:
            buffer = bytearray()
            while future_data:
                data = self._stream.read(future_data)
                if not data:
                    raise IOError('end of file was found')
                buffer.extend(data)
                future_data -= len(data)
            return buffer
        raise IOError('request for zero bytes found')
```